# Jquery Slider UI for displaying Overlay Layer in OpenLayers based on Opacity

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, openlayers

this may seem to be repeated question, as i have gone through many question already available, but as am new to Openlayers, i am not able to get, how should I set my Openlayers with jquery slider, I am able to position it, but it is not working.

I have baske map of OSM and overlay layer is of .png, i wanted to check for opacity so that i caqn check base layer also.

if possible someone could guide.

```
 <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Web Urban Atlas</title>
  <link type= text/css rel = stylesheet href="index_style.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://openlayers.org/api/2.13.1/OpenLayers.js"></script>
  <script src='http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.2&amp;sensor=false' type='text/javascript'></script>
  <script type= "text/javascript" src="main_functions.js"></script>
  <script> 
 defaultLatCenter = 23;
 defaultLonCenter = 77;
 defaultZoom = 5;

 proj4326 = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326");
 proj900913 = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913");

 init = function() {
   gphy = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google("Google Physical", {
     type: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
     });
   osm = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM("openstreetmap");
   map = new OpenLayers.Map("map");
   map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher());
   map.addLayers([gphy, osm]);
   map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(defaultLonCenter, defaultLatCenter).transform(proj4326, map.getProjectionObject()), defaultZoom);


   bounds = new OpenLayers.Bounds();
   bounds.extend(new OpenLayers.LonLat(76.8027, 28.9642));
   bounds.extend(new OpenLayers.LonLat(77.5936, 28.1847));
   bounds.transform(proj4326, map.getProjectionObject());
   radar_overlay = new OpenLayers.Layer.Image('1992_delhi', '1992.png', bounds, new OpenLayers.Size(2706, 2669), {
     'isBaseLayer': false,
     'alwaysInRange': true
   });
   map.addLayer(radar_overlay);
   radar_overlay.setZIndex(150);
   radar_overlay.setOpacity(0.7);

 };

function gotodelhi(){
 // map extent
 var extent = new OpenLayers.Bounds(76.8027, 28.9642, 77.5936, 28.1847).transform(proj4326, proj900913);
map.zoomToExtent(extent);
}

function gotomumbai(){
 // map extent
 var extent = new OpenLayers.Bounds(72.778333, 19.449444, 73.175278, 18.857222).transform(proj4326, proj900913);
map.zoomToExtent(extent);
}
function gotobangalore(){
 // map extent
 var extent = new OpenLayers.Bounds(77.401389, 13.139167, 77.853333, 12.769722).transform(proj4326, proj900913);
map.zoomToExtent(extent);
}
</script>
  <style>
html, body {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
</style>
<script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion();
  });
  </script>
   <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#slider-vertical" ).slider({
      orientation: "vertical",
      range: "min",
      min: 0,
      max: 100,
      value: 60,
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#amount" ).val( ui.value );
      }
    });
    $( "#amount" ).val( $( "#slider-vertical" ).slider( "value" ) );
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body onload="init()">
<div id="header" style= "width: 100%;height:20%;">
<h2>Urban Atlas</h2>
</div>
<div id="map" style= "width:80%;height:70%;float:right;">
</div>
<div id="accordion" style="width:20%">
 <h3 id= "Bangalore" onclick=gotobangalore()>Bangalore</h3>
 <div>
    <p>
  Bangalore is city of gardens
    </p>
  </div>
  <h3 id="setDelhi" onclick=gotodelhi()> delhi </h3>
  <div>
    <p>
  Content For delhi
    </p>
  </div>
  <h3 id="setMumbai" onclick=gotomumbai()>mumbai</h3>
  <div>
    <p>
  Content for mumbai
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="slider-vertical" style="height:200px;float:right"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the `setZIndex()` line.

The code seems right. If not works try to create a jsfiddle sample so we can help you.

In addition you can find samples at OpenLayers Cookbook code samples: http://acanimal.github.io/Openlayers-Cookbook/

See the "chapter02-Creating an Image layer sample".

PS: In addition, there is a new kid on the block, OpenLayers3, which uses a completely different API. You can find help at The Book of OpenLayers3 (https://leanpub.com/thebookofopenlayers3).